# Combine column in data.frame by the same symbols

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I want to combine a list of data.frame by the same symbols in text. Here is my data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(Name = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc","ddd","ggg", "eee"), ID = c("123", "456", "789", "101112", "131415", "161718"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d2 <- data.frame(Code = c("123.aR16", "456d245", "14asadf789", "123_dy6r", "202122-fsd", "101112gh"), CupCake = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If **Code** contains the same combinations of numbers from **ID** -> add new value with data from **Name**.

It looks like copy-paste value from **Name**.

Expected output:

```
  Name     ID       Code CupCake
1  aaa    123   123.aR16      a1
2  bbb    456    456d245      a2
3  ccc    789 14asadf789      a3
4  aaa    123   123_dy6r      a4
5   NA     NA 202122-fsd      a5
6  ddd 101112   101112gh      a6
```

Comment: Can there be multiple matches?

Comment: I think no... ID is unique @RomanLuštrik

Comment: Is this order random or can we expect for row-wise values to correspond to ~ID?

Comment: ID contains only random numbers. @RomanLuštrik

Comment: What I mean is, for row 1 where ID=123, can this ID occur in df2 at any point, or is it placed in row one (or not present at all)? Also, where did `202122-fsd` come from? It's not in your example. Please revise your MRE.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Revised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Create ID in d2
d2 <- mutate(d2, ID = str_extract(Code, "([0-9]+)"))

# Merge d1 and d2 based on ID
df <- full_join(d1, d2, by= "ID")

# Edit: if you only want one row per ID
df1 <- inner_join(d1, d2, by= "ID")

# Or
df2 <- inner_join(d2, d1, by= "ID")
```

Comment: How would you handle cases if ID is not numeric?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. ID is a string variable in the example data given, and in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
d2$ID=NA

for(id in d1$ID)
     d2$ID[grep(id, d2[,1])]=id
# if you want to see all data
dplyr::full_join(d1,d2,by="ID")
# if only interested in matched
dplyr::inner_join(d1,d2,by="ID")
```